# error: could not convert from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'std::tuple<void (xxx::*)(), xxx>'

Tags: c++, multithreading

When compiling my code in godbolt.org I am experiencing the following error:

```
In file included from <source>:5:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.2.0/include/c++/10.2.0/thread: In instantiation of 'std::thread::_State_impl<_Callable>::_State_impl(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = {void (Robot::*)(), Robot&}; _Callable = std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (Robot::*)(), Robot> >]':
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.2.0/include/c++/10.2.0/thread:226:20:   required from 'static std::thread::_State_ptr std::thread::_S_make_state(_Args&& ...) [with _Callable = std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (Robot::*)(), Robot> >; _Args = {void (Robot::*)(), Robot&}; std::thread::_State_ptr = std::unique_ptr<std::thread::_State>]'
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.2.0/include/c++/10.2.0/thread:149:46:   required from 'std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void (Robot::*)(); _Args = {Robot&}; <template-parameter-1-3> = void]'
<source>:154:51:   required from here
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.2.0/include/c++/10.2.0/thread:211:46: error: could not convert '{std::forward<void (Robot::*)()>((* & __args#0)), std::forward<Robot&>((* & __args#1))}' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'std::tuple<void (Robot::*)(), Robot>'
  211 |    : _M_func{{std::forward<_Args>(__args)...}}
      |                                              ^
      |                                              |
      |                                              <brace-enclosed initializer list>
Compiler returned: 1
```

It looks like the error comes when creating the thread using std::thread. A simplified version of the code is:

```
class Robot {

    private:
        vector<double> position;
        double area_covered;
        mutex mtx;

    public:
        Robot(const vector<double> &initial_position) {
            position = initial_position;
            area_covered = 0.0;
        }


        void get_area() {
            // ...
        }
};

int main () {
    vector<vector<double> > path{
      {0.00359, -0.0013},   {0.00608, -0.00281},  {0.00756, -0.0027} };
    Robot r3(path[0]);
    std::thread thread1(&Robot::get_area, r3); // one thread
    thread1.join();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that passing `r3` like this to thread constructor will attempt to make a copy, and `Robot` is not copyable nor moveable (because of `std::mutex`).

You can pass the object by pointer:

```
std::thread thread1(&Robot::get_area, &r3);
```

Or utilize [`std::reference_wrapper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) from `<functional>`:

```
std::thread thread1(&Robot::get_area, std::ref(r3));
```

[See it online](https://wandbox.org/permlink/rrYoG5rUGMpZAnKH)

Comment: Using `reference_wrapper` I get the following error:
```ASM generation compiler returned: 0
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.2.0/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /tmp/ccoHwWZH.o: in function `std::thread::thread<void (Robot::*)(), std::reference_wrapper<Robot>, void>(void (Robot::*&&)(), std::reference_wrapper<Robot>&&)':
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.2.0/include/c++/10.2.0/thread:142: undefined reference to `pthread_create'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status```

Comment: @HectorEsteban That's a linker error. Seems that you need to add `-pthread` to your compiler options.